# Obtener el nombre del equipo en el que esta logueado un usuario

Tags: c#, directorioactivo

Tenemos un sistemita que busca y obtiene la información de todos los trabajadores de un active directory, queremos saber como podemos hacer para saber que **EQUIPO** dentro de la red de la empresa esta usando en ese momento ese trabajador cuando lo busquemos, por ejemplo:

busco al empleado 1111 y dentro la informacion que ya me muestra además me muestre el nombre del equipo en el que está logueado esto porque en `active directory` no vemos ningún `field` que lo diga como tal, como por ejemplo si lo hace el `givenName`, o el sn que nos devuelven nombre y apellido.

Agradecemos cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que se nos pueda brindar

Comment: Aca en stackOverflow en ingles parece la misma pregunta y su respuesta chuequeala y nos cuentas [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153133/search-active-directory-for-computer-names-using-user-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153133/search-active-directory-for-computer-names-using-user-input)

Answer (score -1):

Tendrias que tener conexion al active directory para hacerlo y obtener la información que tiene ahi te dejo un codigo generico solo tendrias que poner los datos de conexión que serian la url el usuario y password.

```
  //los using que use
  using System;
  using System.DirectoryServices;

   try {
        var ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://tu url AD", "usuario", "password");
        var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldap) { Filter = "(objectClass=user)" };

         foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
         {
           DirectoryEntry dirEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                // Puede encontrar la lista de atributos aquí http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090.aspx
                Console.WriteLine("Server name : " + dirEntry.Properties["ServerName"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("IP : " + dirEntry.Properties["ipHostNumber"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("User name : " + dirEntry.Properties["sn"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Email : " + dirEntry.Properties["mail"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Tel : " + dirEntry.Properties["TelephoneNumber"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Description : " + dirEntry.Properties["description"].Value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```